# Why would prices of created potions fall in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Why would the price of potions that I make actually decrease as I get better? I have all the perks and a suit that gives 120% bonus.

Comment: Are you creating the same potion over and over again?

Comment: Try looking at this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36610/why-are-my-enchanted-items-worth-less-and-less

Comment: Try without the suit, I think there's a bug with the pricing of overpowered potions.