# What is the fix (patches, mods, ect.) for the enchanting price bug?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

There is a known bug where the higher your enchanting level when making an item, the less it is worth.  While in the past, I remember being able to exit and restart the game to fix the price, I am no longer able to do such, and have begun searching for some fix to this bug.

See this [link](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36610/why-are-my-enchanted-items-worth-less-and-less) for an old question asking about it (the question was not asking for a fix, so I do not think this would be a duplicate).

Comment: Worth in what way? Money or level? If it is money just enchant  weaponts is worthier.If it is level I think it is a standard behaviour

Answer (score 2):

This bug has not been fixed by anything, however there is an alternative method in which you could use which may restore some of the item's value - however this can only work if you have unlocked master conjurations spells as it requires you to cast Dead Thrall.

Kill someone first, then store your enchanted items in them. Afterwards, cast Dead Thrall, and then promptly kill them. Loot your items back, and there is a possibility that your items will have restored value.

Note that this method is just as temperamental as the restarting method and is not guaranteed to work.